# Three.js json loader error without changing file extension

Tags: json, three.js, blender, loader

I created a model in Blender and then exported it to JSON using Three.js official exporter. Then I tried to load it using the next code:

```
const loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load('assets/models/bear.json', (geometry, materials) => {
  const bear = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));
  scene.add(bear);
});
```

Then I got the error:

```
(unknown) TypeError: url.split is not a function
  at Object.extractUrlBase (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:742), <anonymous>:32860:19)
  at JSONLoader.load (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:742), <anonymous>:33166:120)
```

Here is my json file: https://github.com/elliepooh/VRcard/blob/master/src/assets/models/bear.json

I found some decisions, but they all are about renaming the .json file to .js and load it instead. Since I'm using webpack and eslint, it is problematic for some reasons...

I also tried to use Clara.io JSON loader code this way:

```
const loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
loader.load('assets/models/bear.json', (obj) => {
  scene.add(obj);
});
```

And then I got the following TypeError: url.lastIndexOf is not a function

If there any method of loading json to three.js without changing it's file extension and without having such errors? Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: For some reason is doesn't like your URL. Could you please paste the full error form your console? Thanks!

Comment: My guess would be the JSON  is referring to a texture with a value that is a not string url. I am guessing this because only the texture loader utilizes url.split in the extractUrlBase function of loader, which is used by JSONLoader. I would advise to post your JSON on codepen and see if it loads there, so others can replicate the error.

Comment: @Radio thanks for suggestions! I edited the description with more information

Comment: @TheJim01 thank you for considerations! I've just updated error description

Comment: Or better yet, use a SO snippet. ;) The weird thing is: you're passing in a URL string, and `split` is complaining about that. If you can't share your code, place a breakpoint at `loader.load` and follow it down into `extractUrlBase` where you'll see the `split` function being used. Ensure the URL is still a string...

Comment: Here is the file: https://github.com/elliepooh/VRcard/blob/master/src/components/cards/greeting/BearCard.js (and there is also the repo)
Thank you again, @TheJim01
I will try to do what you suggested

Comment: **1)** Aha, I see your `bearModel` is actually from an `import`. Have you tried it with just a string, like you have in the code in your post? **2)** Which transpiler are you using? If `import x from "@...."` doesn't return a string, then that's the problem, because `loader.load` expects the first parameter to be a valid URL string.

Comment: @TheJim01 I see now! Didn't now about it. I've just tried to load it with a string (not an import), but now I always get 404 error... Also I've checked it several times. The path is right, don't know why it can't find it

Comment: It looks like your assets are at the root of your project. Try your URL as: `/assets/models/bear.json`. The `/` at the front references the root of your server (unless your server/framework defines otherwise). Otherwise try a fully qualified URL (http://...etc...) to see if your server is actually replying with the JSON.

Comment: It works! I moved the file to static folder and finally the model was loaded. Thank you so much, @TheJim01 :)

Comment: I'm glad you got it working! Please consider writing up your solution as an answer and accepting it, so others can see your problem was resolved. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in importing the .json file. Instead I should have loaded it with a string. (as it was in description, but I used @import in my code)

Now it looks this way:

```
const loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load('/static/bear.json', (geometry, materials) => {
  const bear = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));
  scene.add(bear);
});
```

Great thanks to **@TheJim01** for his help!